# How can i get the correct binary array in the loop to visualize a bubble sort?

Tags: javascript

I was try to visualize a bubble sort with JS.I use a binary array to save each changed array.But in the binary array i only get array which has been sorted.

```js
var arr = [1, 5, 3, 7, 2];
var newArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length - 1 - i; j++) {
    if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
      arr[j] = arr[j] + arr[j + 1];
      arr[j + 1] = arr[j] - arr[j + 1];
      arr[j] = arr[j] - arr[j + 1];
      console.log(arr);
      newArray.push(arr);
    }
  }
}
```

I can't understand why i get the right result in the loop when i console arr[],but the newArray is [1, 2, 3, 5, 7],[1, 2, 3, 5, 7],[1, 2, 3, 5, 7],[1, 2, 3, 5, 7].

Why in the same scope the console and the push function get the different results?

How can i get the correct binary array?

i'm a newbie and completely confused about it.Does someone know the reason? Thank you

Comment: *"Why in the same scope the console and the push function get the different results?"* It doesn't. In each iteration you are changing `arr`. In JavaScript, arrays are reference types, i.e. the array is not copied when you pass it to a function or assign it to a variable. Here is a simple example to demonstrate the issue: `var arr = [1,2,3]; console.log(arr); /*1,2,3*/ arr[0] = 4; console.log(arr); /*4,2,3*/`. The second `console.log` shows a different array because I changed `arr`.

Comment: You are pushing a _reference_ to the same array onto `newArray`. You end up with the same array multiple times in `newArray` so, of course, they are all identical. You need to *copy* each member into a new array and push that onto `newArray`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what exactly you are trying to do, but I think your idea is to have `newArray` contain a snapshot of the array at each step of the sort. Your code doesn't work because you are pushing *the same* array into `newArray` at each step. You need to make a *copy* of the current `arr` at each step. Luckily, this can be easily done with `slice`:

```js
        var arr = [1,5,3,7,2];
        var newArray = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {            
            for (var j = 0; j < arr.length - 1 - i; j++) {
                if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                    arr[j]   = arr[j] + arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = arr[j] - arr[j+1];
                    arr[j]   = arr[j] - arr[j+1];
                    //console.log(arr);
                    newArray.push(arr.slice(0,arr.length));
                }
            }
        }
console.log(newArray);
console.log(arr);
```

Now `newArray` is an array of array containing a snapshot of the array at each step of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs normally because `.push()` passes a pointer to `arr`. Therefore, `newArray` stores 4 pointers to `arr`. To solve this problem, you should, like the answer above does, pass a copy of `arr` each time.